# Load CSS file only if element with class is present on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to optimise my loading of CSSS files as I am loading some large CSS files on pages where they aren't used. Is there any way for me to enqueue them only if an element is present with a class on that page.

I've tried the following however, it does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //Script Checkers
    var wowJS = $('.wow');

    if (wowJS.length > 0) {
        $.getScript('/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/js/wow.js', function() {
            new WOW().init();
        });

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var cssNode = document.createTextNode("link");

        cssNode.href = "/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/css/animations.css";
        cssNode.rel = "stylesheet";
        //console.log("CSS Node: "+cssNode); = [object Text]

        head.appendChild(cssNode);
    }
});
```

I have seen functions that work for adding css files to the head however, none of them allow the ability to make it conditional.

**EDIT: I've since just used the getScripts() jQuery function however, I am still in need of knowing how to add css to the header only if required.**

**EDIT: For future reference for anyone, this is the final working code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //Script Checkers
    var wowJS = $('.wow');

    if (wowJS.length > 0) {
        $.getScript('/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/js/wow.js', function() {
            new WOW().init();
        });

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var cssNode = document.createElement("link");

        cssNode.href = "/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/css/animations.css";
        cssNode.rel = "stylesheet";

        head.appendChild(cssNode);
    }
});
```

Comment: `appendChild()` accepts a new Node or Element, not a string. Also note that if you've included jQuery in the page you can simplify this with `$.getScript()`

Comment: I’ve also tried with just append, to no success

Comment: Thinking about it wrong regarding wp_enqueue. You would conditionally enqueue based on whatever conditions would make that class available in the page. Not sure if it is categories, page template used , content related etc

Comment: The only condition would be that a shortcode has been used and an element with a class is present which I don’t believe is best done or capable in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the nodes first then append then using the `appendChild()` method, like :

```
var scriptNode = document.createElement("script");
scriptNode.src = "/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/js/wow.js";

var cssNode = document.createElement("link");
cssNode.href = "/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/css/animations.css";
cssNode.rel = "stylesheet";

head.appendChild(scriptNode);
head.appendChild(cssNode);
```

Comment: And should I wish to load a script in the footer how would one append the footer area just inside of the closing body tag?

Comment: Call `appendChild()` on the `body` node instead of the `head`

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said you need just to specify the element

Comment: I've updated my answer with my current code, it does not create or link the elements. And I have used alert() to check the value of wowJS it returns "1"

Comment: createElement does indeed fix it, didn't get notification of your comment and I just stumbled upon the answer myself lol

Comment: Good job @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You should use `insertAdjacentHTML`

```
head.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",'<script language="javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/js/wow.js"></script>');
head.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",'<link href="/wp-content/themes/gowebsites/gw-addon/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet">');
```